# vectorization of an integral in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, integral

Reproducing a part of the original question to simplify the problem.

I need to calculate the integral of this function

```
def f(z):
    return ((1-2*z)*np.exp(-d/z))/(((1-z)**(2+d))*(z**(2-d)))
```

Here d is a constant. I am using this function:

```
 import scipy.integrate as integrate
 return integrate.quad(f,0, 5)
```

However, I need to calculate this for many different d values. I tried putting all d values in a numpy array but it didn't work. Any idea how to vectorize this?

Comment: The key question when attempting to vectorize is, can you perform the actions in parallel?  Second, if the actions are iterative, do they use the same number of iterations.  Problems that are inherently serial, or produce 'ragged' results are not 'vectorizable' in the usual `numpy` sense.

Comment: The code sample you provided is not runnable as is and includes several errors / undefined variables. From your post in scicomp I see that `c`, `k`, and `m` are "constants", but that leaves a lot of room for assumption.  Also, it doesn't look like `c` even makes it into your code.

Comment: Ok thanks, will edit it soon to try to make it runnable